# Number of elements of a subset of $\mathbb F_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I wish somebody could help me in this. I encountered this question in a previous year paper of an exam.

Let $F$ be a field with $8$ elements and $A=\{x\in F\mid x^7=1$ and  $x^k \ne 1$ for all natural numbers $k<7\}.$ we have to find the number of elements in $A$.

Comment: m not sure whether this question belongs to linear algebra or modern algebra.

Comment: It belongs to the set of questions copy-pasted from some unnamed source with no sign of any effort by the person posting them.

Comment: actually, i did go through 'field' topic. i solved sample questions. but m not getting how to start this question.

Comment: How to start: the non-zero elements of a field form a group under multiplication. The order of an element of a group divides the order of the group. That should start and finish the problem for you.

Comment: i apologize for this question. i should have been more specific about my doubt or i should have mentioned the source if i was to paste the question verbatim. i respect your time and concern, and will try my best to stick to the guidelines next time onwards. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: $F\setminus\{0_F\}$ is a multiplicative group of order $7$.

Comment: let the order of A be m. order of x is 7. now, 7 should divide m. m can be 7/14/21... but that's not an option. clearly m thinking on wrong lines. i would appreciate help.

Comment: @Ramit: $A$ contains those elements of $F^\times$ that are of order $7$ in the multiplicative group $F^\times$. What are the possible orders of elements in a group of order $7$, and how many elements have each of those orders?

Comment: Why does the order of $x$ divide the order of $A$? As far as I can tell, $A$ is not even a group...

Comment: @User84559: It doesn’t necessarily. And no one said that it did.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott possible orders of elements, in a group of order 7, would be 1 and 7 i believe. and in general, how many elements would have each of these orders, i've no idea. but i guess in this case, no element would have 1 order. as by defn, each elmnt is of 7th order. and now, 0 is already excluded, 1 can't be there as its order is not 7. so A has 6 elements. is that correct?

Comment: @Ramit: Yes, $1$ and $7$ are the only possible orders of elements of $F^\times$, because the order of any element of a group must divide the order of the group. The identity is the only element or order $1$ in any group, so every other element of $F^\times$ must have order $7$. As you say, there are $6$ of them, so $|A|=6$ is correct.